# Issues Getting Button to Change Label Text

Tags: java

Recently I've been trying to make a program that takes in a double in the form of a string. It then parses that to a double which goes to another class to be divided to a quarter or a half and then returns that output to a label.

I've been having an issue where when I click a button to actually submit what is inside the text field, the label doesn't change.

I've tried a lot of trial and error and I know I can change the text after doing new JLabel("test") for example. However, there seems to be an issue with my action listener for when the button is pushed. I can't tell if it's not seeing the button as being pushed.

**NOTE:** I am new to awt event things and swing as a whole, I usually operate just using the output terminal of visual studio code where it's just text and no graphics.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class MoneySorterRunner {
    
    private  MoneySorter sorter = new MoneySorter();

    private String input = "0";
    private double money = Double.parseDouble(input);
    private static JTextField typeHere = new JTextField();


///labels num1-3 are the labels being changed
    private static JLabel num1 = new JLabel(new MoneySorterRunner().sorter.divQuarter(new MoneySorterRunner().money));
    private static JLabel num2 = new JLabel(new MoneySorterRunner().sorter.divQuarter(new MoneySorterRunner().money));
    private static JLabel num3 = new JLabel(new MoneySorterRunner().sorter.divHalf(new MoneySorterRunner().money));

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Money Calculator - v0.1a");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton doThing = new JButton("Do a Thing");
        doThing.setActionCommand("Do a Thing");
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 250);
        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel item1 = new JLabel("test");
        JLabel item2 = new JLabel("test");
        JLabel item3 = new JLabel("test");
        item1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        item2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        item3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        num1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        num2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        num3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        Dimension size1 = item1.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size2 = item2.getPreferredSize();
        Dimension size3 = item3.getPreferredSize();
        panel.add(item1);
        panel.add(item2);
        panel.add(item3);
        panel.add(num1);
        panel.add(num2);
        panel.add(num3);
        panel.add(doThing);
        panel.add(typeHere);
        item1.setBounds(10, 10, size1.width + 3, size1.height);
        item2.setBounds(190, 10, size2.width + 3, size2.height);
        item3.setBounds(325, 10, size3.width + 3, size3.height);
        num1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 25);
        num2.setBounds(200, 50, 50, 25);
        num3.setBounds(350, 50, 50, 25);
        doThing.setBounds(250, 150, 100, 25);
        typeHere.setBounds(100, 150, 150, 25);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String check = event.getActionCommand();
        if(check.equals("Do a Thing")){
            input = typeHere.getText();
        }
        if(input != "0"){
            num1.setText(sorter.divQuarter(money));
            num2.setText(sorter.divQuarter(money));
            num3.setText(sorter.divHalf(money));
        }
    }

}
```

**For those who wanted the MoneySorter.java:**

```
    public MoneySorter(){

    }

    public String divQuarter(double moneyIn){
        String answer = Double.toString(moneyIn);
        return answer;
    }

    public String divHalf(double moneyIn){
        String answer = Double.toString(moneyIn);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code for MoneySorter?

Comment: [Java Client Technologies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm)

Comment: the code doesn't do much yet, if you were to see it all you would see is a method that returns it's input as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that your program is supposed to do the following.

User enters an amount of money in a `JTextField` and when she clicks on a `JButton` the `JLabel`s show the entered amount in dollars, half-dollars and quarters (as per U.S. currency). My answer, below, is based on this understanding.

I don't know if making all the variables static is good or bad but I never use static class member variables in my *Swing* programs.

Here is my analysis of your code.

```java
private double money = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

This line of code will be executed precisely once, when you launch class `MoneySorterRunner`. You want to do this every time the `JButton` is clicked, hence parsing the text entered into the [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) should be performed in the [actionPerformed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) method.

```java
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
```

It is almost never needed to set the [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to null. You can almost always find an appropriate layout manager or you can place one `JPanel` within another and use different layout managers for each `JPanel` in order to get the desired placement of [components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) within the *Swing* application [window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

```java
JButton doThing = new JButton("Do a Thing");
doThing.setActionCommand("Do a Thing");
```

By default, the text of a [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) is also its *action command* so no need to explicitly set it.

```java
frame.setLocation(200, 200);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

These are two different ways to set the location of the `JFrame` and they do not complement each other. Use one or the other, but not both.

```java
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Only after you have created all the [GUI] components and added them to the `JFrame` should you make the `JFrame` visible. So this should be the last line of the code that creates your GUI.

```java
doThing.setBounds(250, 150, 100, 25);
```

If you use a layout manager, you never need to call method `setBounds`.

```java
if(input != "0"){
```

This is not the way to [compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Use method `equals` as you have done here

```java
if(check.equals("Do a Thing")){
```

Here is my rewrite of your application. Note that since I could not find the code for class `MoneySorter`, in your question, I just created my own version of that class. The point is to show how to change the text of the `JLabel` after clicking on the `JButton` and not how to create the actual text to display.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MoneySorterRunner implements ActionListener {
    private MoneySorter sorter = new MoneySorter();
    private JTextField typeHere = new JTextField();

    private JLabel num1;
    private JLabel num2;
    private JLabel num3;

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Money Calculator - v0.1a");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(createLabels(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createForm(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(550, 250);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createForm() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 0));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0, 0, 0));
        typeHere = new JTextField(10);
        panel.add(typeHere);
        JButton doThing = new JButton("Do a Thing");
        doThing.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(doThing);
        return panel;
    }

    private static JLabel createLabel(String text) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        return label;
    }

    private JPanel createLabels() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        num1 = createLabel("num1");
        panel.add(num1);
        num2 = createLabel("num2");
        panel.add(num2);
        num3 = createLabel("num3");
        panel.add(num3);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MoneySorterRunner().createAndShowGui();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String check = event.getActionCommand();
        if(check.equals("Do a Thing")){
            String text = typeHere.getText();
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                double money = Double.parseDouble(text);
                num1.setText(sorter.divQuarter(money));
                num2.setText(sorter.divQuarter(money));
                num3.setText(sorter.divHalf(money));
            }
        }
    }
}

class MoneySorter {

    public String divQuarter(double money) {
        return "divQuarter(" + money + ")";
    }

    public String divHalf(double money) {
        return "divHalf(" + money + ")";
    }
}
```

This is how your GUI looked when I ran your original code (as posted in your question).

[image: original app screen capture]

This is how the GUI looks when running the code in this answer.

After launching

[image: my app after launch screen capture]

After entering a value and clicking the `JButton`

[image: my app after button click]

Comment: This is good but I specifically didn't want to use a layout so I could do it myself, also the other class only takes in the double money after it's been parsed and changes it back into a string to be displayed as one of the 3 labels called num1-3 that sit right below item1-3. item1-3 I never want to change those but num1-3 change to become whatever is put in the text field, for testing it just returns what it receives as a string, but later it will do something else, which is why MoneySorter is not included, if it were the program would start up and show 0.0 under the 3 top labels.

Comment: this helps tho and thanks for the response, I will attempt to implement this however I still plan to leave out a pre done layout, personally I've never been a fan of those.

Comment: I am glad to say I was able to successfully able to implement this solution, it might anger a few people that I decided to not use a layout manager, but I wanted absolute positioning in this and have better personal experience making the GUI layout myself.
Once again thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to set the `ActionListener`. You should also change your method to another name, because your method has the same name as the `actionPerformed` of the `ActionListener`.

```
doThing.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new MoneySorterRunner().actionPerformedMethod(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I attempted to implement this but it did not help, I added it to my main method and replaced .actionPerformedMethod(e); with the name of the method which I changed to .buttonDidThing(e); 
am I implementing it wrong or something?

Comment: did you also change the name of the method to ```public void buttonDidThing(ActionEvent event){}``` ?

Comment: Yes I did otherwise I would've gotten an error saying the method didn't exist

Comment: I am curious btw, could part of the problem be that I'm doing everything with swing inside of the main method? I have seen the main method can't access non static things

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean and what it is in the main method, but you have to do ```new MoneySorterRunner().actionPerformedMethod(e)``` you can also do this from the main method. If something is non static, you need to make an object of it to access methods. Like ```Object name = new Object(); name.yourMethod()``` or ```new Object().yourMethod();```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the ActionListener.
In order to fix this, you need to do two things:

1. Add this statement to your code, preferably near where you create the button (so that it is easier to keep track). -

```java
doThing.addActionListener(this);
```

2. When you write "public class", you also need this keyword: `implements ActionListener` - meaning your class (basically the first line) should look like:

```java
public class MoneySorterRunner implements ActionListener
```

And that should make it work.

Comment: I also tried implementing this but I got something that said I can't use doThing.addActionListener(this); in a static context, specifically the "this" in the parentheses. I have no idea what this means tbh